# How to show previous div after user get error message and prompted to insert field again

Tags: javascript, html, thymeleaf

I have a specific situation and I'll give my best to explain it.

On page I have a select field, inside it I have two choice for user, that looks like this:

```
<select id="payment_type" name="payment_type">
    <option>Select a payment type...</option>
    <option value="Income">Income</option>
    <option value="Expense">Expense</option>
</select>
```

Now I have a `JS` code that show `form` for `income` or `expense`, depends which one user has selected:

```
$('#payment_type').on('change', function() {
var val = $(this).val();
$('#Income').hide();
$('#Expense').hide();
$('#' + val).show();
});
```

So if user has selected `Income` from dropdown list I will show him this form:

```
 <form action="#" id="Income" class="hidden" th:action="@{/api/transaction/saveIncome/{walletId} (walletId=${id})}"
      th:object="${transaction}" method="POST">

    <label for="amountIncome" class="col-form-label">Amount</label> <input
        type="text" th:field="*{amount}" class="form-control"
        id="amountIncome" placeholder="amount"> <span
        th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('amount')}" th:errors="*{amount}"
        class="text-danger"></span>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{note}" placeholder="Enter note" class="form-control mb-4 col-4">
    <input type="date" th:field="*{date}" class="form-control mb-4 col-4">

    <select th:field="${transaction.incomeCategories}">
        <option value="0">Select income category</option>
        <option
                th:each="incomeCategories : ${incomeCategories}"
                th:value="${incomeCategories}"
                th:text="${incomeCategories.displayName}"
        ></option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info col-2"> Save Wallet</button>
</form>
```

Now, If the user entered wrong value for `amount` I will provide him error, and that works fine. But what is the problem, I will provide you a use case:

Here user pick the transaction type:

[image]

Now, user has selected `Income` for example, and I provide him form for `Income:`

[image]

Now, If user for field amount insert `-1` I will provide him an error, but I'm redirected to this page again:

[image]

And when I select again `Income` only then I can see the error:

[image]

While I want to display him immediately form that he picked from list. So if he choose `Income` but made error on form, display him again `Income` form without having to choose again from dropdown menu.

The only solution so far that I have on my mind is to create a totally separated HTML pages with form, but I think that there is for sure a way to solve this on another way without that.

I give my best to explain problem and added picture for better understanding, for anything else I'm here to explain or to provide more information. Thank you and also sorry for my bad English.

Comment: I thinks you meant the JavaScript tag

Comment: Can you add a reproducible example of your use case and explain what you expect it to happen and what it's currently doing?

Comment: I literally put a pictures on question how its work now and I explained how it should work? You must be kidding. About  reproducible its hard to achieve since this is also Spring Boot thing, but I think that I provide a very useful information and gave my best to explain all stuff

Comment: Basically, the main problem is that after user enter a wrong value he need to select again option from dropdown menu, but what I want to achieve is that, okey user insert a wrong value, show him again div that he previously selected